Show JSF EL call hierarchy in Eclipse 2023-09
I want to be able to see Expression Language calls in the call hierarchy of a JSF bean method as in this question, but for the most recent JBoss-supported Eclipse release, 2023-09 (I would have just asked this in a comment on that question but I don't yet have enough reputation for that).
The accepted answer on that question recommends the extension "JBoss Tools", but when I followed the steps on the JBoss Tools website to install the software and then checked the call hierarchy of a method used by EL, there was no change in the result. I also tried installing the most recent version of JBoss Tools from the Eclipse marketplace, again with no success.
Is there still a way to see EL calls in the call hierarchy in modern JBoss Tools / Eclipse?
